# If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $Au_n \rightharpoonup b$, does it follow that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}(Au_n, u_n) \leq (b, u)$ if $A$ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A:H \to H$ be a (nonlinear) continuous map.

If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $Au_n \rightharpoonup b$, does it follow that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}(Au_n, u_n) \leq (b, u)$$
by any chance?

I know it is not true for $\lim$, but maybe $\limsup$ is nicer.

Comment: Note that operators $A: V \to V^*$, where $V$ is a separable reflexive Banach space satisfying that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$, $A u_n \rightharpoonup b$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u, u_n \rangle \le \langle b, u \rangle$ imply that $A u = b$ holds, are said to have the property (M). All pseudomonotone operators have this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take a Hilbert space with a sequence $u_k$ such that $||u_k||=1$ while $u_k\rightharpoonup 0$. Then take $Au=u$. You have $(Au_k,u_k) = (u_k,u_k) = 1$ while $(u,u)=0$.